# How can I bind a list to a datagrid in WPF?

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a list that contains objects. Within these objects are 6 double arrays. I need to be able to display these arrays in columns in a datagrid.

I have tried to figure out how to bind the list to the datagrid and it has frustrated me most of this day.

Can someone give me step by step instructions as to how I can bind this list of objects to a datagrid ?

The list is just needed for show. It is read only.

(For the person that looked past the wording and provided a solution, thank you)

Comment: What do you mean by six double arrays? Six items of type double in an array? Six arrays of arrays? Could you post some sample code showing the construction of your arrays?

Comment: List with "6 double arrays" means what? Something like a list like this `List<string[][]>` having 6 items in it? If so, you would have to convert one dimension of these items into a `DataGrid.Columns` collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an ObservableCollection and Bind the collection to the ItemsSource property of the GridView.

You can try this article :
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/datagrid-in-wpf/

If you are providing your Custom object and want to get better control, define DataTemplate and specify the properties yourself and make AutogenerateColums to false.

Comment: I ended up doing this and it worked

Comment: Thank you for answering the question. It seems that people who have no answer to a question attack the question instead of moving on to something they know.